# How do I reinstall MediaScannerService?

Tags: media-scanner

I recently rooted my Samsung Exhibit II. and was going through and deleting some bloatware and accidentally fat fingered and deleted the MediaScannerService not realizing what I was deleting.  Does anyone no how to reinstall the service?  I have tried downloading applications but they are just accessing the service and restarting it.  Since the service has been deleted the applications essentially do nothing.

Comment: you will need to pull it out of a ROM for your device (might be able to use 'non-device specific' version but I would use the same to "be safe" then copy it on to the device. The other option is to reflash the stock ROM (if you have it available from somewhere). - Always Nandroid Backup before making changes, or use titanium backup and Freeze first to "test" for issues.

Comment: +1 for the *Freeze* recommendation! It's the first thing I always recommend in such cases, as its reversion is much easier than a re-install. Having a backup before removing stuff should be *that* obvious -- though many users seem to forget this most important step. First thing after rooting is installing a custom recovery and doing a Nandroid backup.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways to get it back:

1. Flash a (new) ROM. This could be the same you are currently using, or any other one fitting for your device. To find a matching one, please see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)
2. Find the exact ROM you are currently using, and extract the corresponding files from it. Then copy the extracted files to your device.

For the future, keep in mind to always make a good [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) before tampering with system files. A [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup is a very good idea, as with that you are always able to get back to the state *before* you started with any changes.

See also the comments on your question for other details.

Comment: When copying file set the permission as `644` and it should be copied to `system/app`